# delete custom customer attribute in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom attribute for customer in Magento.

I have accidentally set wrong type for my attribute.

Now I want to either modify this attribute or delete this one and then create new attribute.

Can any one tell me whether I can delete or modify custom attribute in magneto or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an upgrade script in one of your modules with this content:

```
$this->updateAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code_here', 'type', 'varchar'); //or any other type
```

Basically you can change any attribute from customers, categories & products like this;

```
$entityType = 'customer';//or catalog_category or catalog_product
$attributeCode = 'attribute_code_here';
$changeWhat = 'field_name_here';
$changeInto = 'new value here';
$this->updateAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode, $changeWhat, $changeInto);
```

To remove an attribute run this:

```
$this->removeAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code_here');
```

It follows the same rules as above.

Comment: any idea to delete attribute also. Actually I have to change label for 
one attribute also.

Comment: @Marius can you please answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634111/magento-error-when-disable-module

Comment: How we can delete Tax/VAT Number attribute of customer from magento 2 customer Registration ?